# What is this C Syntax called?

Tags: c, syntax

What the hell is this?  How is this allowed and legal?
I swear, every time I think I'm getting a grip of how this language works, some real cute looking syntax like this shows up.

This is from Semtech's example project for one of their radios.

From within *radio.h*:

```
   void    ( *SetRxConfig )( RadioModems_t modem, uint32_t bandwidth,
                              uint32_t datarate, uint8_t coderate,
                              uint32_t bandwidthAfc, uint16_t preambleLen,
                              uint16_t symbTimeout, bool fixLen,
                              uint8_t payloadLen,
                              bool crcOn, bool FreqHopOn, uint8_t HopPeriod,
                              bool iqInverted, bool rxContinuous );
```

If there's justice in Heaven, how is it OK to write something like this?  What is this chunk of code doing and what is it called so I can look up more about it?

Comment: That's just an ordinary function pointer.

Comment: A handy tool for assisting in learning how to interpret complex declarations is "cdecl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This declares a function:

```
int foo(int, float, double);
```

> And this defines (or declares - depending on context) a function pointer, that can be assigned the address of function `foo`:

```
int (*function_pointer)(int, float, double);
```

This is what you are seeing here.

A more verbose explanation with additional examples on how to use, pass as argument and return function pointers can be found in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/2179300) suggested by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112).

Possible uses include:

- A library defines hooks to it's function where you can make it call your code. Either by defining a global variable (like `void * (*mymegalib_malloc)(size_t size)` where you can replace the allocator by your own), or by providing setter functions for the function pointer like in `signal`,
- Passing a function to do stuff to another function, like in `qsort`, where you pass an array, the number of elements and a function, that compares two indices of that array - giving you the opportunity to let `qsort` operate on whatever data structure you want,
- Creating some jump tables, like this:

  ```
  struct jmp {
      char op;
      double (*func)(double a, double b);
  } jtable = {
      { '+', add },
      { '-', sub },
      { '*', mul },
      { '/', div },
      { 0, NUUL },
  };
  // in some function:
  for (size_t i = 0; jtable[i].op; ++i) {
      if (jtable[i].op == requested_op) {
          result = jtable[i].func(a, b);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: "And this defines a function pointer" - without further context, this is a declaration. We cannot know if it is also a definition.

Comment: @Olaf: `int foo(int, float, double);` always only declares a function. `int (*function_pointer)(int, float, double);` however can declare (e.g. in a <code>struct</code> or argument list) or define (e.g. in file or function scope) a function pointer. I defined it to define a function pointer, this narrows down the places, where I expect this construct to show up.

Comment: It it **always** a declaration, regardless if it is also a definition. But it is only a definition for variables with block-scope. And your `struct` is not a defintion at all, but a _type-specifier_ in the first place (specifically a _struct-or-union-specifier_), and forms a _declaration_ without _declarator_. Feel free to read the standard, if you want to use the correct terms. Btw.: what is an "argument list"? This does not exist in C.

Comment: I talk english not standardish.

Comment: this is what two wizards fighting looks like.